# Difference between Tape and File In Backup Device

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

When I create a new Backup Devices in SQL Server Management Studio, I can choose the destination option, tape or file. What is the difference between both of that options?

Comment: Does anyone still use tape as a backup medium?

Comment: The tape options is disabled in my PC.

Comment: @MarkKram A lot of places use tapes as backup especially for off site storage.

Comment: Ask your boss to purchase some tapes to wrap up your database server, that's what doing back up using tapes means..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back up to File (Disk) means you backup the database to [hard drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive).
Back up to Tape means you backup the database to [tape drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_drive).

It was disable, because the tape drive is not connected to your computer physically  or OS does not support the tape drive.